# Meteor Handsontable example

Tags: meteor, handsontable

does anyone have a working example using meteor and handsontable to create a reactive table to read and update the data?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Sup @lobosan, already tried something? some package? check out this package [handsontable package](https://github.com/olragon/meteor-handsontable), I think if you ask any example or demo, is a little hard for people to come and help, if you accept an advice, try some code(maybe the package), by yourself and if you get stuck come back here and try asking but with some code references or something

Comment: Were you able to put a minimal working demo together? If yes, could you share it as a meteorpad app? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example works as a reactive table that reads and writes data, including paste and autofill.

I'm not aware of a Meteor smartpackage that makes available the standard Handsontable API. (There is one smartpackage by Olragon, but it's for the jQuery API of Handsontable). You can add the files to your project directly fairly easily:

- Download the latest release from https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/releases
- Unzip and copy dist/handsontable.full.js and dist/handsontable.full.css to one of your project's client directories (e.g., /client/lib/)
- Open handsontable.full.js and change the following line:

  ```
  // Remove "var" from Handsontable declaration to add to global scope
  var Handsontable = function (rootElement, userSettings) {
   ...

  // New code
  Handsontable = function (rootElement, userSettings) {
   ...
  ```
- You may need to uninstall any existing Handsontable smartpackages

Next add a new template to your html where your Handsontable will be located:

```
<template name="handsontable">
<div class="handsontable" id="hot"></div>
</template>
```

Finally in your js file:

```
Meteor.isClient {
 Template.handsontable.rendered = function () {
  var myData = [];  // Need this to create instance
  var container = document.getElementById("hot"); 
  var hot = new Handsontable(container,{  // Create Handsontable instance
    data: myData,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    contextMenu: true,
    afterChange: function (change, source) {  // "change" is an array of arrays. 
      if (source !== "loadData") {  // Don't need to run this when data is loaded
        for (i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {   // For each change, get the change info and update the record
            var rowNum = change[i][0]; // Which row it appears on Handsontable
            var row = myData[rowNum];  // Now we have the whole row of data, including _id
            var key = change[i][1];  // Handsontable docs calls this "prop"
            var oldVal = change[i][2];
            var newVal = change[i][3];
            var setModifier = {$set: {}};   // Need to build $set object
            setModifier.$set[key] = newVal; // So that we can assign 'key' dynamically using bracket notation of JavaScript object
            MyCollection.update(row._id,setModifier); 
        }               
      }
    }
  });  

  Tracker.autorun( function () {  // Tracker function for reactivity
      myData = MyCollection.find().fetch();  // Tie in our data
      hot.loadData(myData);
  });
 };
}
```

Docs on afterChange API is here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Events

This code will render your collection's fields as columns automatically, including an _id column. To define columns using Handsontable in Meteor, here's an example document in the sample collection Books:

```
{_id: 'Hneb7LxFRptXCiL49',
 title: 'The Name of the Wind',
 author: 'Patrick Rothfuss',
 copies: 3 }
```

We can specify our columns so that _id does not show up, as well as (optionally) give names to our colHeaders:

```
// replace at "colHeaders":
colHeaders: ['Title','Author','Copies'],
columns: [
  {data: 'title'},
  {data: 'author:},
  {data: 'copies'}
],
// ...
```

Comment: Hi @Mufasa, thank you for your answer. Your code is working but in the first column appear the id of the documents. I'm trying to hide the column #0 by adding this configuration property of Handsontable , `columns: [{data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3}]` but then the whole table is not rendered. Same problem when I use property cells. Any suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: See updated answer. You specify columns as: [{data:'field1'},{data:'field2'}]

Comment: BTW you can't reference columns as you indicated because you're working with an array of objects (because you're using a Meteor collection), rather than a 2D array. See the "Object data source" examples on HT docs https://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Mufasa for your patience and detailed support. The code is working pretty well now. Keep working hard as you are doing it and your reputation will go higher and higher. All the best ;)

Comment: Ok, I was able to accomplish, what is in the current post. I missed the insert-delete part. So I added an afterCreateRow hook, but when I do an insert in afterCreateRow, it causes an infinite loop.