# Meteor Handsontables not showing with schema.

Tags: javascript, meteor, handsontable

Hi there I am trying to use handsontables which works fine when I hard code the data but when I try use a schema which is what i need cant get it to work.  I have been following this old post [Meteor Handsontable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701527/meteor-handsontable-example). I have done everything except change

```
// Remove "var" from Handsontable declaration to add to global scope
var Handsontable = function (rootElement, userSettings) {
 ...

// New code
Handsontable = function (rootElement, userSettings) {
 ...
```

I cant seem to find this anywhere.

What I have is.

**products.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Product = new Mongo.Collection('product');

ProducSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    m1: {
        type: Number,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    m2: {
        type: Number,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    m3: {
        type: Number,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    m4: {
        type: Number,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
});


Product.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return !!userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only remove your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    fetch: ['owner']
});



Product.attachSchema( ProducSchema );
```

**productSingle.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {  Product } from '../../../../../api/lists/Products.js';

import './ProductSingle.html';


if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.ProductSingle.onCreated(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.autorun(() => {
            self.subscribe('product');
        })
    });


    Template.ProductSingle.rendered = function() {
        var myData = []; // Need this to create instance
        var container = document.getElementById("productSingle");
        var hot = new Handsontable(container, { // Create Handsontable instance
            data: myData,
            startRows: 5,
            startCols: 5,
            colHeaders: true,
            rowHeaders: true,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            afterChange: function(change, source) { // "change" is an array of arrays. 
                if (source !== "loadData") { // Don't need to run this when data is loaded
                    for (i = 0; i < change.length; i++) { // For each change, get the change info and update the record
                        var rowNum = change[i][0]; // Which row it appears on Handsontable
                        var row = myData[rowNum]; // Now we have the whole row of data, including _id
                        var key = change[i][1]; // Handsontable docs calls this "prop"
                        var oldVal = change[i][2];
                        var newVal = change[i][3];
                        var setModifier = {
                            $set: {}
                        }; // Need to build $set object
                        setModifier.$set[key] = newVal; // So that we can assign 'key' dynamically using bracket notation of JavaScript object
                        MyCollection.update(row._id, setModifier);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
            myData = Product.find().fetch(); // Tie in our data
            hot.loadData(myData);
            console.log(myData);
        });
    };

}
```

This doesn't show any table just the the first row header like so .

[image]

If i click on this is get a error:

```
awsp_handsontable.js?hash=45775ff…:25594 Uncaught Error: column 0 does not exist(…)
```

If someone could help me figure this out would be great this has been a big road block for me so far